# session needs to be automatically destroyed after redirect if session data is in other language(other than english)

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am using **codeigniter 2.2.1** and i have major issue in **session**.
when i am trying to store session value in **chinese or other language**  session **destroy after redirection** of page.

any one have idea how to handle this error.my website is on 72 languages and i have to store some session variable in multi-language. any body can guide me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if session is destroyed in other language(other then english) then check a **collection** of **mysql table ci_session**. this table is automatically **generated by codeigniter**. change the collection to **Utf8_general_ci** session will be working fine on **all languages**.